# Find a radio button in a row not having a certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to exclude some radio buttons from  a table row. Below is my code.

`$(this)` is reference of a table row. I want to do something for each radio in this row where radio class(css) name is NOT "disabled" but this is ignoring it. Am I using the selectors wrong?

```
$(this).find('input[type="radio"]').not(".disabled").each(function () {
    //some code
});
```

Comment: Should work. can you share the html and rest relevant code?

Comment: Well that wont be possible. I have 2 radio buttons in that particular row and both radio buttons class="disabled" so i would expect that control must not enter in the each block as it won't find and radio button not having that class name.

Comment: Better show complete code, Just to make sure your $(this) is actually a table row, other than that your code looks good

Comment: Atleast show us single row of html having radio buttons and javascript event.

Comment: Logically that should work. The problem should be something else.

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/huny25tx/. Working fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem the css name was misspelled. thanks all.